# Particles don't collide with rigid bodies

Tags: particles, physics, collision

I have a scene with 2 Cubes, **Cube 1** (using a soft body (Rigid body doesn't work either))falls through **Cube 2**, and **Cube 2** has a particle system on it. I want **Cube 1** to "push away" the particles on **Cube 2** however, goes straight through. I have *Collision* physics on **Cube 1**, but it doesn't seem to interact with the particles at all.

Here is my .blend file:

[image]

also: to clarify, i don't want the two cubes to collide, I want the particles on **Cube 2** to colide with **Cube 1**

Comment: Can you add some more details or a screenshot?

Comment: And I have soft body physics on the thing that falls. Maybe that's why?

Comment: That's possible. If your running a simulation on an object, Blender might want particles to collide where the mesh was initially.

Comment: Is there a fix? add it as an answer if yes.

Comment: Can you upload a .blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com ? I could then look more closely.

Comment: You can bake it, but that's not quite the same, I don't believe.

Comment: I tried to bake it but, nothing. Also, I'm uploading it to your website thing.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look at it. You can __edit__ your post and post the link there.

Comment: Got it. Typing up an answer now.

Comment: Posted! Please consider accepting if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you were trying to do with the *Soft Body Physics*, but what you really need is a *Rigid Body Physics* simulation. You can learn a bit about it in this quick, fun [tutorial](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/quick-tutorial-make-a-wrecking-ball-with-rigid-body-physics/), but it is basically a simplified physics engine for gravity and whatever else you want to have affect your **meshes**.

For the falling-through-the-bottom-box issue, I turned off *Collision* Physics for all of the meshes except the floor because it has to deal with the particles. I changed some settings to make the particles bounce nicer. I also added all of the meshes to the *Rigid Body Physics* simulation. You can tell this because when you select them, the outline is green instead of orange. Additionally, I adjusted the particle settings so that they began emitting at the collision of the two boxes.

*Final result:*

[image]

Here is the modified .blend file:

[image]

Comment: It works nicely, but it's not the look I was looking for.

Comment: @snipers500 Perhaps you could have added more details about the look you were looking for in your question? I did the best I could and made some assumptions based on limited data. I do apologize if it didn't work for you. However, you said in your answer that you changed to rigid body physics? So maybe my answer helped a bit? If it did, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need soft body you could use ridged body. Just add rigid body on both cubes. Remove soft body on all of the cubes/objects. The add ridged body on the plane and check animated.